# Why an error is being showed on top when I open my settings on Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play-console

When I go to settings of google play console I see an error on top saying "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (4600000)". I am assuming it is because of a problem with my merchant account.

In "Account details" tab of settings my merchant account is showing active status.

But in "Payment settings" tab an error is shown saying "Uh oh. There was a problem.
This payments profile has been closed. To continue paying, contact the Support team for this product. [OR-CAC-13]"

Previously I deleted this email account and recently recovered it. Is this the reason behind my described problem?
If so, how can I get recovered from it and add a new merchant account to it?

I am providing necessary screenshots:

[Image of "Account details" tab of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgJN4.jpg)

[Image of "Payment settings" tab of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeT2s.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was automatically solved after chatting with google support team about my problem.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you contact Google Play support or Google Payment support? thank you.

Comment: Yes, I chatted with Google Play support.

Comment: thank you so much, I've recently deleted my Payment Profile, and I've created a new one, and I was hoping I can link it with my Google Play console, but I get that message "Uh oh. There was a problem..." is that was your situation ?

Comment: My problem was solved automatically after chatting with the Google support team.

Comment: thank you, so you just deleted your payment profile, and then you recover it right ? That's why this issue appear in your account ? My apologies for asking too many questions because I'm stuck at this issue

Comment: I understand your situation. But as it is an incident of a long time ago, I can't remember whether I deleted my payment profile or not, but I deleted my google account.